# Is there a "place" to deposit and, or publish reports produced in grad school?

Tags: graduate-school, open-science, repository

I am looking for some kind of repository where I can "publish" my reports from grad school.

I'd like to do this because it would be great if I could link those works with my ORCID and make them available to the public and to (hopefully) improve my online appearance.

Comment: What kind of reports?

Comment: More importantly, what field are you in?

Comment: I am studying biology and therefore occasionly write reports summarizing literature about a specific topic. Recently I have written some works with data that I have produced myself, concerning plant genetics.

Comment: Is the question [Is it advisable to upload your PhD thesis on Biorxiv?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/77661/546) helpful to you?

Comment: I have considered the option of sending the reports to Biorxiv, or ArXiv. But it seems to me, that my reports do not fit their conditions, as they're not likely to be published in real journals later on.
What I am trying to get at is, if there's is a repository for such work that enables one to google them.

Comment: If you upload them to your own website, Google Scholar will find them. (https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html)

Comment: For arXiv, it's not a requirement that the paper is "likely" to be published in a real journal.  The standard is "refereeable", i.e. is this the kind of paper that a journal might conceivably publish, if it were submitted?  Lots of people submit things to arXiv that they have no intention of ever sending to a journal, and that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense to share your work online as long as you make sure to do some quality check. Students can benefit from availability of this type of material and it can indeed improve the online presence of the author.

### Quality check

- Check for English correction as best as you can. I would strongly suggest [languagetool.org](http://languagetool.org) as an excellent tool for this.
- Do not copy direct parts from other authors, make sure not to plagiarize. This is something that takes time and is often overlooked. Clearly point out where you are quoting and where words are your own. Always give author's name, date and page where the information was obtained. Here is an excellent source in the subject: [Melbourne University Student Skill manual](http://services.unimelb.edu.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0004/821668/5297-Avoiding-PlagiarismWEB.pdf)
- Conform to one citation standard and check correctness of the citations (provide a doi whenever possible).
- Use an open science tool, so to permit transparency of the contents. This is particularly important if your report includes statistics. Have a look in the [Knitr R package](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) or my own [Mighty_Make](https://lf-araujo.github.io/2017/04/08/mightymake.html).

You can list any material you want in your ORCID page. However, do that clarifying which material was peer-reviewed, and which was not. Graduation level reviews goes in the group of non-peer-reviewed scientific contributions.

### Where to publish?

This is the easy part, a very effective tool is [zenodo.org](http://zenodo.org). Once you feel your document is ready for submission, you can upload it there, and you will have a doi for your material so it can be cited and tracked.